# Allow user to enter escape characters in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, escaping

I have a Windows.Forms.TextBox that I'd like to allow the user to enter escape sequences that are then interpreted as the character they represent.

For example, if the following is entered:

```
Hello\r\nWorld
```

I'd like it to be stored as the character array:

```
   H     e     l     l     o    \r    \n     W     o     r     l     d
0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x57, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64
```

Thus far, I'm using the following to handle '\r' and '\n', but I'd also like to be able to handle any other escape sequence, like `\u001A` (ctrl+z), or `\u001B` (esc)

```
string str = txtBox.Text.Replace("\\r","\r").Replace("\\n","\n");
```

...There has to be a more general way of handling this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to use the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx) static method:

```
string str = Regex.Unescape(txtBox.Text);
```

But unfortunately it applicable mainly for Regex control characters.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  I knew the simple answer was just eluding me... Thank you!