# Convert text entered by user containing with escape sequence to string

Tags: c#, string

In textbox1 user enters string "Test\u0021Test" and I would like to convert escaped character "\u0021" to "!"

```
string x = "Test\u0021Test"; // this is easy
string y = textbox1.Text; // here textbox1.Text = "Test\u0021Test" and this I don't know how to convert
```

Thanks for help

**EDIT**
Answered by @Simo Erkinheimo
[Allow user to enter escape characters in a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150970/allow-user-to-enter-escape-characters-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Replace \u0021 by !

Comment: \u0021 is only example. User can put any unicode character with \u

Comment: [Allow user to enter escape characters in a TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150970/allow-user-to-enter-escape-characters-in-a-textbox)

Comment: Are other then `\uxxxx` escapes like `\n`, `\xAB` allowed?

Comment: @Simo Erkinheimo, please add it as answer, this solve my problem and from my point of view it is most readable solution

Comment: @kurin123 Flagged as dublicate so someone with more rep can close this.

Answer (score 1):

Use string `Replace` method this case

```
string x = "Test\u0021Test"; // this is easy
string y = textbox1.Text.Replace("\u0021", "!");
```

Comment: \u0021 is just example, I don't know what escape character he will put in

Comment: so what will be the criteria or patter after escape character ? when the pattern end ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. It will work for all unicode escaped symbols in input string.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(x, @"\\[u]([0-9a-f]{4})",
match => char.ToString(
    (char)ushort.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)));
```